# Indenting VHDL as other programming languages

Tags: indentation

When I write VHDL Vim uses a mix of tabs and spaces which aim to align columns beneath the last parenthesis. For example, Vim will produce something like

```
Inst_IMem: IMem PORT MAP(
                            CLK => clk,
                            ADDR => foo,
                            DATA => bar
                        );
```

instead of

```
Inst_IMem: IMem PORT MAP(
    CLK => clk,
    ADDR => foo,
    DATA => bar
);
```

How can I make Vim indent VHDL as it would indent programming languages such as C and Java? I.e. a new indentation level (either a tab or say four spaces) for every new nesting level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fairly simple, you only need to use:

```
:let g:vhdl_indent_genportmap = 0
```

And you're done :-)

I found this in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/vhdl.vim`:

```
" option to disable alignment of generic/port mappings
if !exists("g:vhdl_indent_genportmap")
  let g:vhdl_indent_genportmap = 1
endif
```

Which is used further below:

```
if g:vhdl_indent_genportmap
  return ind2 + stridx(prevs_noi, '(') + &sw
else
  return ind2 + &sw
endif
```

So if it's off (0), it will only indent a single `shiftwidth`, if it's on (1), it uses the location of the `(` on the previous line + `shiftwidth.

This (and some other things) are also documented in [`:help ft-vhdl-indent`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/indent.txt.html#ft-vhdl-indent); I found this page by typing `:help vhdl` (a number of filetypes have their own help pages).